# Can gulp-uglify strip out console.log statements?

Tags: gulp

As the question states. I know gulp-uglify can uglify with a simple:

```
gulp.src('filename')
.pipe(uglify())
```

Is there a way to tell it to strip out console.log statements too?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Much better still: you can use the specialized gulp plugin: [gulp-strip-debug](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-strip-debug). It doesn't only strip out console statements, but also alerts and debugger statements.

> Strip console, alert, and debugger statements from JavaScript code with [strip-debug](https://github.com/sindresorhus/strip-debug)

install it using:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-strip-debug
```

and use it like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var stripDebug = require('gulp-strip-debug');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/app.js')
        .pipe(stripDebug())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: gulp-strip-debug doesn't seem to support sourcemaps... https://github.com/gulp-sourcemaps/gulp-sourcemaps/wiki/Plugins-with-gulp-sourcemaps-support

Answer (score 27):

Yes there is!
As gulp-uglifyjs documentation mentions you can pass extra options ( [gulp-uglifyjs documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglifyjs)):

```
uglify([filename], [options])
```

All available options can be found on [the compressor UglifyJS documentation page](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/compress#global-defs). From that 'drop_console: true' should help:

```
uglify([filename], {
    compress: {
         drop_console: true
    }
})
```

Comment: This plugin is deprecated

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify mentions that the gulp-uglifyjs options still work (minus something about sourcemaps)

Comment: Yes, this option still appears to be valid, also for gulp-uglify (without the JS). Go to https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify and follow the "minify options" link https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#minify-options. In "Compress options" section it says "drop_console (default: false) -- Pass true to discard calls to console.* functions."

Answer (score 5):

With [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) (not gulp-uglifyjs) you can remove arbitrary code by using a strategy similar to [compilations constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swfss70d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) with the [compression configuration](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/compress) (Link goes to *gulp-uglifyjs*, but should be the same for *gulp-uglify*):

```
.pipe(uglify({
    compress: {
        global_defs: {
            "DEBUG": false
        }
    }
}))
```

And then in your code write something like

```
if (DEBUG)
{
    console.log("Application started...");
    //...
}
```

if you set DEBUG in global_defs to true, gulp-uglify will remove the conditional but leave the inner branch. In case DEBUG is set to false, it will remove both.

*drop_console* as in Fill's answer does not seem to be supported in gulp-uglify.

Comment: How would this work? In you code example without running gulp-uglify, `DEBUG` is undefined, so there is no console output. If you explicitly put `DEBUG=true` in your code, will it then be overridden by gulp-uglify?

Comment: @Peter These variables are not supposed to get out to runtime. They should only be used for this kind of precompilation.

Comment: @Peter Of course you could also use global constants that are defined and functional in runtime, but this is a compile-time transformation and it will optimize away the use of these variables when you run your build script. So if you run this build script, it's irrelevant what the value of the variables would be runtime.

Comment: Alex, either I don't understand you or you don't understand me. I am assuming that in a debug build, you would you like to output "Application started..." But it seems to me that in that same debug build, you would never get that output, but instead a undefined variable error. Because your DEBUG variable is only defined in the uglify script.

Comment: @Peter When you run this build script it is changing the code to remove the if statement completely. If the build constant is false it removed both the if and the code within, if the constant is true it just removes the if but leaves the code within.