# How can I remove some console.logs from minified files, while retaining others?

Tags: javascript, gulp

We are establishing a code base on a new platform. During development, a lot of console.logs have been used and most of these I want to remove for production deployments. Since the platform is new enough, however, I'd like to keep some of those logs to both provide an nice monitor that things are running as expected and to assist in the inevitable trouble-shooting that will be needed once the new code goes live.

I have a nice Gulp setup that will do the various builds and have seen the plug-ins that will easily remove **all** the console.logs, but nothing I've seen lets me easily mark some console.logs to be retained.

I could go through and wrap everything I want to keep in code like:

```js
if (PROD) {
  console.log('keep this log in production');
}
```

But that seems cumbersome and won't necessarily prevent an automated tool from remove the nested console.log. What I'm hoping for is something like:

```js
// keeper
console.log('keep this log in production');
```

To flag lines to keep when otherwise minifying the file.

Comment: You shouldn't ever be making changes to minified files. Edit the original files, then minify them again.

Comment: I don't think they are making changes to the minified files. I think they are editing the original files, but when the minified files are being generated the `console.log`s are being removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can gulp-uglify strip out console.log statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943734/can-gulp-uglify-strip-out-console-log-statements), more precisely answer from Alex

Comment: I'd suggest tagging the code revision deployed to production to be able to debug it in development mode and avoid having any console logs in your minified production code.

Comment: You can do something similar with this. It allows you to skip individual statements. https://github.com/valeriansaliou/gulp-remove-logging